# Maven not pulling in dependencies at three levels down

Tags: maven, dependencies

In my application, I have dependency on activemq-core,
the chain looks like this

```
activemq-core > fusemq-leveldb > hadoop-core > commons-configuration > commons-collections
```

I used `CircularFifoBuffer` from `commons-collections` in my application. It compiles fine but when I write a test it fails at the runtime with ClassNotFoundException.

I come around it by adding the dependency at the top level.

Any reasons why the transitive dependency was not working.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I would advise you to run:

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose
```

It could be that some other transitive dependency overrides a version you are expecting/hoping to use. Check your tree with this detailed report and you'll be able to figure it out, I am sure.

Comment: For maven-dependency-plugin > 3.0, the command is: `mvn dependency:tree -X`

Comment: Thanks! This will be useful for future references! :)